# How to enter insert mode capitalizing the first letter I write?

Tags: vim

I'm doing a repetitive task for which I defined a macro in one of the F-keys, but I still have to hold the shift down to type the first letter every time I execute that macro. I wondered if that can be included in the macro too, but my search for ways to do that was unfruitful.

There are many ways of entering the insert mode, relating to the position of the cursor in the text. But can I define a macro that capitalizes the first letter I write after entering the insert mode, and only that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, this is kinda a hacky solution but it seems to work. I'm not exactly sure how you want to map it, so I mapped it to `<leader>i` in my example. Feel free to change this to whatever you like.

```
function! Icap()
  augroup icap
    au InsertLeave * exec "normal! \<C-o>gUlgi\<esc>:augroup icap | au! | augroup END\<cr>"
    au InsertEnter * exec "normal! m`"
  augroup END
endfunction

nnoremap <leader>i :call Icap()<cr>i
```

What this does is defines a function "Icap" (short for 'insert capitalize') that sets up two autocommands. The first autocommand, is that right before entering insert mode:

- Vim adds the current location of the cursor to the [jumplist](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/motion.html#jumplist).

Then after calling foo, and immediately after leaving insert mode, the following will happen:

- Vim types `<C-o>gUl`. This will jump to your previous location in the jumplist, and convert the character under the cursor to uppercase. After this, vim types `gi<esc>`. This is a hacky way to get the cursor back to the previous location. In theory, `<C-i>` should work, but as I was testing it I ran into strange problems.
- Vim deletes every autocommand belonging to this function. This is to prevent future insert mode changes from making weird edits you didn't want.

You could also do a mapping like this:

```
nnoremap <leader>i :call Icap()<cr>
```

which would then allow you to use other commands to enter insert mode (`c`, `a`, `I`, `o`, `s`, etc.) and still get the capitalization side-effects.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but besides the delayed effect, that is okay, the cursor ends over the capitalized letter, not where I finished typing, and that is a deal breaker for me. If you correct this I will accept your answer.

Comment: @ReneSac See my edit

Comment: Hacky, but I see myself using it for more than just that macro I was doing, especially with my <leader> being <space>. Thanks.